# Javascript date method without time

Tags: javascript, date

Javascript method

```
var d = new Date();
```

get datetime value, but how get clear date, without time ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: d.toJSON().substring(0,10)

Answer (score 13):

For complete reference of parsing date Follow link [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

You can simply parse only date from you variable like

```
d.toJSON().substring(0,10)
```

or

```
d.toDateString();
```

Answer (score 8):

I would advise you to use **dayjs** or **momentjs**  (http://momentjs.com/) for all your javascript problems concerning dates.

This code will reset hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds of your javascript date object.

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(0);
d.setMinutes(0);
d.setSeconds(0);
d.setMilliseconds(0);
```

Or in a simplified way:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Or as a one line function:

```
function now () { const d = new Date(); d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); return d }

now(); // returns the current date
```

Without conversion, and you still have a date object at the end.

Comment: This could be shortened to: `var d = new Date(); d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 5):

There are so many examples of this..

```
function format(date) {
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    return '' + y + '-' + (m<=9 ? '0' + m : m) + '-' + (d <= 9 ? '0' + d : d);
}

var today = new Date();
var dateString = format(today);
alert(dateString);
```

I also like to point out whenever dealing with time.. MomentJS really is the perfect tool for the job

[MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/)

another super simple example...

```
var today = new Date();
alert(today.toLocaleDateString());
```

second example is my favourite.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what format you like, I think these are the easiest ways to get just the date without the time.

```
new Date().toJSON().split("T")[0];
// Output: "2019-10-04"
```

or

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString().split(",")[0]
// Output in the US: "10/4/2019"
```

Answer (score 4):

I always use this method, it will return only current date:

```
var date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);
```

Answer (score 1):

With `Date` you have a date **object**, which has several methods. A complete list of methods can be found in the [Javascript Date object documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

In your case:

```js
var d = new Date(),
    datestring = '';

datestring = d.getFullYear() + '-' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '-' + d.getDate()

alert(datestring);
```

Answer (score 1):

`new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB').format(new Date('2018-08-17T21:00:00.000Z'))`

The result will be: **18/08/2018**

You can check the [description](http://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) here.

Answer (score 0):

```
const dateWithoutTime = new Date(Math.floor(date.getTime() / 86400000) * 86400000)
```

Comment: Could do with some explanation

Comment: It converts the date into a millisecond-precision Unix timestamp (`getTime()`) and divides it by the number of milliseconds in a day (86,400,000). This allows to shift the time portion into decimal values which are then truncated using `Math.floor()`.